# Select con Join dos tablas

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla1 tal que así:

NUMERO
SALE
LLEGA
TIEMPO

y otra tabla2:

CODIGO
NOMBRE

En la tabla1 los campos SALE Y LLEGA tienen los códigos de las poblaciones. La tabla 2 relaciona poblaciones con códigos
ZARAGOZA=1
MADRID=2
ETC

Quiero hacer una consulta en la que los campos de SALE y LLEGA de la tabla1 aparezcan con los nombres de las poblaciones de la tabla2.

Gracias

Comment: Necesitamos ver la estructura de las tablas, y datos de ejemplo, si no es imposible ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

teniendo en cuenta la siguiente estructura de tablas a modo de ejemplo.

```
CREATE TABLE `tabla1`(
`numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sale` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`llega` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`tiempo` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`numero`),
KEY `tabla1_tabla2_fk_1` (`sale`),
CONSTRAINT `tabla1_tabla2_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`sale`) REFERENCES `tabla2` (`codigo`),
CONSTRAINT `tabla1_tabla2_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`llega`) REFERENCES `tabla2` (`codigo`))

CREATE TABLE `tabla2` (
`codigo` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nombre` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`))
```

El Select se estaría realizando de esta manera.

```
select t.numero,t2sale.nombre as sale ,t2llega.nombre as llega ,t.tiempo 
from tabla1 t
inner join tabla2 t2sale on t2sale.codigo=t.sale
inner join tabla2 t2llega on t2llega.codigo=t.llega
```

En donde se crea un alias para cada columna que se desea mostrar y/o unir
Ejemplo

```
t2sale= tabla2.columna =sale 
t2llega=tabla2.columna=llega
```

Espero haberte ayudado.